# log4net configure same appender for two dll namespaces

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I would like to understand how can I configure the same appender for two different namesapaces.

I have:

WPF.Client.Foo class in first dll

WPF.Server.Foo class in second dll

I want all logs in both classes to be traced with same appender to the same file.

Currently I passed the same string to the ILog in both classes but I don't like it because in the future maybe I will need to change this name or add additional dlls. I can't use a constant because every dll is independent and do not have references to any other dll.

I don't want to configure two loggers with same appender (and different name/namespase) in the Logger.config file because if the logs are enabled, it should be always enabled for both Dlls and I don't want to update two thresholds in the config file.

Merging the code to one dll is not an option.

Am I wondering if there is an easy way to configure many namespaces to same appender when the namesapaces are completely different and not a child of each other.

Thank you.

Comment: "I don't want to update two thresholds in the config file" - you don't need to do that.  You could, for example, configure the root logger to log to your appender, and this will be inherited by all loggers unless explicitly configured otherwise

Comment: @Joe I can't because the root logger will trace all the application and I need only two dlls. I don't understand why log4net doesn't provide this simple functionality. There is a way to do that? or define a threahold parameter at the top of the file that can be used in both appenders to change only on one place?

Comment: Instead of the root logger, you could configure a logger with a name that is common to your two DLLs ("WPF" in your example).

Comment: @Joe The two dlls have completely different names. I dont want to put a string instead TypeOf because if the name need to be changed then I need to change it in every dll. I don't want to hse a constant because dll are not using a mutual reference. I want a way to configure somehow two or more namespaces for same appender. Like Root but for only few dlls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up an `appender` linked to the `root` logger, and let the `appender` do the filtering upon the loggers using two [`LoggerMatchFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Filter_LoggerMatchFilter.htm) rules.

The last `DenyAllFilter` filter in below configuration ensures that anything that doesn't match the expected logger names doesn't appear in the output.

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">

    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="INFO" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
    </filter>

    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
      <loggerToMatch value="WPF.Server.Foo" />
    </filter>
    
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
      <loggerToMatch value="WPF.Client.Foo" />
    </filter>
    
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
    
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.ffff} Thread: [%thread] %level %logger%exception - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>  
</log4net>
```

```csharp
namespace WPF.Server
{
    public class Foo
    { }
}

namespace WPF.Client
{
    public class Foo
    { }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Logger configuration left out for brevity.
        
        var logger1 = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WPF.Server.Foo));
        logger1.Error("Hello from WPF.Server.Foo"); // Will appear in the log.

        var logger2 = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WPF.Client.Foo));
        logger2.Error("Hello from WPF.Client.Foo"); // Will appear in the log.

        var logger3 = LogManager.GetLogger("WPF.Other"); // Will not appear in the log.
        logger3.Error("Hello from other");
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented the solution today. The filter works for RollingFileAppender but it doesn't work for a custom apender I made (derived from AppenderSkeleton). What am I missing?

Comment: Weird and interesting... Since the out-of-the-box  appenders behave appropriately, the issue will not be in the filter setup. Please post a new question with (the most important part of) the code of your appender.